# AndroiStudio test fails with Class Not Found Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

When I try to run my test it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:260)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: junit.textui.ResultPrinter
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried most of solution that I could find online but nothing helped to fix and it gets really annoying. Any tips to fix that ?

Comment: Be more specific as to how you tried to solve the problem. Also, could you post some of your code so we could see where the problem lies.

Comment: I'm following an android cors held on udacity and this is the code I've added: https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/tree/lesson_4_starter_code . I've tried to run the test using Junit and android instrumentation, sync'ing project and removing configuration under "Run.." tab but none of these worked.

Comment: Are you using a maven project...?

Comment: No, I'm not using a maven project